# How to make .aspx file serve a download? IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am running a website with IIS and I simply use .html and .php for my actual web pages not .aspx or anything like that.

I am trying to make it so when you goto mywebsite.com/something.aspx that it will actually download the .aspx file rather than trying to render the page of it.
However, everytime I go to it, it simply gives me a HTTP 500 error.

I have under my MIME types the following:

```
.*      application/octet-stream
.       application/octet-stream
.aspx   application/octet-stream
```

However, it still is giving the 500 error and not simply downloading the file.
Thanks!

Comment: Gee, sometimes we get these award winning questions and have to ask why? If you not using aspx pages, then why bother? Those pages have to be pre-processed by the server and that includes the rich event model and nice code behind written in a nice language like C# or vb.net. Once that page is processed by that code, then web compatible HTML is created and sent to the browser. I am at a loss as to why use aspx pages and then not let the server load them? Only client side way to do this is a client side passing of the URL to the server and then server takes over.

Comment: sounds like to try to hack a web site - I see no reason why you want to direct download an .aspx file alone.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Hardly an award winning question there bud... Like I stated in my first sentence, I am not running aspx pages on the web server. Only HTML and PHP pages. The aspx files are part of the game files that need to be downloaded. 
Already figured out the issue, thanks though for your guys' concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove the ASPX from HTTP headers in IIS.
Not sure how to close this, but the problem is already solved.